# How to display GPS coordinates on mobile app(ios)

Tags: ios, arduino, gps

I am trying to build a GPS tracking device that would be displayed in my ios app.

I am using GPS tracking device [ADAFRUIT ULTIMATE GPS BREAKOUT](https://www.adafruit.com/product/746) and I could display the GPS coordinates in `a
Arduino IDE serial monitor.

But since my Arduino-uno does not have access to the Internet I can't send the GPS coordinates to my database.

**My question:**

In order to display GPS coordinates in my app, I need GPS coordinates in my database so that I can fetch the data using http.

But how can I send GPS coordinates to my database if I don't have Internet access?

I am very new to GPS so I don't really know how it works. Any advise or comments would be really helpful.

Comment: If you go out and buy a GPS device, or a GPS enabled device like a watch how do they communicate.... it's either wifi or mostly bluetooth. Your arduino needs to have some form of communication method.

Comment: @Scriptable thank you for the comment. I still have a question, for example, what about `gps` in `bird-dockless scooter` Do you think they also use `wifi` or `bluetooth` to communicate?

Comment: no idea... I don't even know what that is

Comment: can't you use a gsm module in your Arduino + GPS setup ?

Comment: Bird scooters probably use a cellular data connection. You will need som sort of communications add-on for your Arduino; wifi if your device will always stay in range of your wifi network or cellular if you want the device to be connected when away from wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some sort of Internet connectivity for your Arduino. Assuming you want to be able to track the device outside of your home/office (I.e. away from your WiFi network), you will probably want a [cellular shield](https://www.google.com/search?q=arduino+cellular+shield&oq=arduino+cellular+shield)